# Want to create a Lead Time chart based on the selection of two releases rally

Tags: extjs, extjs4, rally

Want to create a Lead Time chart based on the selection of two releases rally
like below[image]

Something like this, with the options to select two releases start release and end release. So this chart should be prepared for those releases time period, rather than for whole year.

Any suggestions, examples for this. Which calculator should I use. Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cycle/Lead Time cannot be customized beyond what's available in the Settings because it is actually a report served by a legacy analytics service. Generally, this applies to all the reports available on Reports>Reports page even when they can be installed via AppCatalog. Anything that can be accessed via [StandardReports component](https://help.rallydev.com/standard-reports) available in older AppSDK1 falls into this category. AppSDK2 also has a thin wrapper over it via [Rally.ui.report.StandardReport](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.report.StandardReport) but the same limitation applies since underneath it is using the same built-in reports that predate [LookbackAPI](https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/doc/#/manual).

If you decide to write an app from scratch that displays cycle time use AppSDK2's [SnapshotStore](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/#!/api/Rally.data.lookback.SnapshotStore) that gets historic data from LookbackAPI.